# Update a Java Class so that a List can Accept Any Type

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
public class MyList {

    private List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>();

    public List<X> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<X> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

I want this class to be able to handle lists of types other than "X". For example, what if I wanted it to be able work with Lists of Y? I don't currently know all the types that I may need to handle, so it should be able to handle any types.

Comment: Make the class generic?

Comment: Do you want the same `MyList` to possibly have objects of different types (heterogeneous list), or do you want each `MyList` to contain elements just of one type?

Comment: For my specific use case, the class itself is a raw type but I need the list it contains to be a generic list that can contain any type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into using Java generics on your class.

```
public class MyList<T> {
```

Then wherever you have `X` before, you can now have `T`, e.g. `List<T> list`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I should have been more specific in my question - the class itself needs to be a raw type since it's used to hold an xstream transform from XML to List.

Comment: Turns out that I was able to accomplish this using Generics. The problem was the return type when popuplating the List. It needed to be <T> MyList<T>